# Singular or plural verb when referring to an individual and then a group

Tags: verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Singular or plural following a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/singular-or-plural-following-a-list)
>   [Mixing plural and singular list items with a single verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59808/mixing-plural-and-singular-list-items-with-a-single-verb)

Which is correct?

> The Mayor and City Council has...
>
> The Mayor and City Council have...