# "This chapter, and the following chapters in this section" — singular or plural?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I have some technical documentation that has the phrase:

> This chapters describes how to...

And I need to upgrade it to refer to the current and following chapters. What is the correct English phrase to use?

> This chapter, and the following chapters in this section, describes how to...

or:

> This chapter, and the following chapters in this section, describe how to...

In other words, is the thing doing the describing a multitude of chapters (that would "describe" something), or are the multitude considered a single item here (needing "describes")?

Or, are both phrases wrong?

Comment: The last one is right. Conjunctions form plurals.

Comment: I don't think you need the commas: "This chapter and the following chapters in this section describe how to..." Also, I wonder, can you simplify the sentence by saying "The chapters in this section describe how to..."? (That is possible, of course, only if **all** of the chapters in the section describe how to do that thing.)

Comment: @JLG, that's _much_ better than my tortured version. Yes, the entire section does he describing so I think I'll go with that. Both commenters should post them as answers, I would think, so I can properly reward.

Comment: Related: [Singular or plural following a list](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/), [Mixing plural and singular list items with a single verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59808/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to repeat "chapters":

"This and the following chapters describe how to ..."

Plural verb agrees with the compound subject in this case.

There's a good segment on compound subject verb agreement here:

http://www.towson.edu/ows/moduleSVAGR.htm

If you need to include information about the section, then you can get away with something like:

"In this section, this and the following chapters describe how to ..."

If you like, you can get away from the use of "in this section" altogether by doing something like:

"This chapter through chapter 15 describes how to ..."

Oddly, the singular verb seems to agree here since now it is a single subject--a nounal phrase which operates as a collection--rather than a compound subject. It is like saying:

"This *collection* of chapters *describes* how to ..."

Comment: Ended up going with "The chapters in this section describe ..." which is similar to your "This chapter through ..." one.

Comment: Ah yes. That's perfect, actually.

Comment: The reason I didn't suggest that is because I wasn't sure if it was all chapters in the section or all chapters after a specific chapter within the section. :)

Answer (score 0):

In reality, you'll find both used: either a plural verb to agree with the conjunction of both terms or a singular to agree with the 'main' subject and disregarding the parenthetical phrase.

As in practice this is a borderline case, then I would personally take a stance either way:

- if you feel that both subjects are on 'equal footing', then why not remove the commas and let them stand together, possibly with the rearrangement suggested by @JLG in the comment above?;
- if you feel that the second subject is truly parenthetical, then why not emphasise that fact by replacing "and" with a phrase such as "along with", "as well as" (in which case speakers would more clearly opt for a singular verb)?