# "there comes times" or "there come times"?

Tags: verb-agreement

There comes times in...
OR 
There come times in...

Please help. I do not want to say "There comes a time..."

Comment: We need to see more of the sentence.  But your first option is definitely not correct.

Comment: Closely related: [“There Is”/“There are” depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not).

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding whatever the rest of your sentence may be, `"There come times in..."` is correct, while `"There comes times in..."` is never correct.

The subject of the sentence ("times") is plural, so the sentence must use a singular verb.

That's why the common phrase is "There comes a time". In that phrase, the subject "time" is singular, so the "conjugation for third-person singular (he, she, it)" [1] is required, which is "comes".

[1] From Brian Hitchcock's comment below on this.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning explicitly that the word  'there' is not a noun and so it is not the subject of the sentence. The subject of the sentence is 'time[s]'. You can rearrange  the sentence as, "Times come there..."

Comment: First comes helvetica in a large point size. Then there comes times in an even larger point size.

Comment: "comes" is NOT a plural verb! It is the conjugation for third-person singular (he, she, it).

Comment: Yeah, the verb *comes* is decidedly singular, not plural.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware. Could @BrianHitchcock or Anonym shed some light on what the correct reasoning for this answer would be, then? I assume I'm "right" but got there with the wrong reasoning.

Comment: You're right, and used correct reasoning, but used  the wrong term ("plural") to describe the verb.