# Which one is correct - " There is only us here" or "There are only us here"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, subjects

**Temporary reopen note:**

The linked-to question is about the verb agreeing with the grammatical number of the first item in a list in a *there is/are* sentence. However there is no list in this question here. Even if there were, *us* would seem to be plural here, so there is no good explanation of why *is* may be preferable to *are*.

You can see the linked-to question here:

- ["There Is"/"There are" depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not)

**The Original Question**

I am dubious between these two ways of referring to two people in a place or in an area.

Example:

> John: Ok folks, I am going to let you here waiting for the manager to come. It is going to take some minutes until he makes it here.
>
> Josh: Ok, thank you.
>
> Mathew: Alright.
>
> Josh: Hum... Now, there is/are only us here.

Is there any reason why *is* or *are* is preferable here?

Comment: I consider that the upvoter is doing the site a disservice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth what about the "us?"  Clearly wrong but idiomatic...?

Comment: @michael_timofeev It's as clearly wrong as it is in 'It's us' rather than 'It's we'. Idiomaticity trumps zombie rules. The absurd 'the copula and other link verbs must never take the accusative' pseudorule has been debunked here many times. And the agreement issue involved here has also been done to death.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think this is a dupe of that question. There is no coordination of phrases here, just the one pronoun. This is also a good question because it gives strong evidence that *us* is not the Subject of the verb here. So, in fact, there is no clash between idiomaticity and *us* being in accusative case. I think this is a fantastic question, although it looks a bit underdeveloped at first sight. Any chance of a reopen?

Comment: @michael_timofeev It's not wrong, because it's not the Subject of the verb ;-) Also it's not wrong because it's what people say!

Comment: @Araucaria chat room on this one?

Comment: @Araucaria what's the link again?

Comment: I feel like this should be reopened. Franky as a native, none of the possible combinations of *there[['s|'re]| is| are] [we|us]* sound right to my ears, though I can't come up with an explanation as to why. I think it is quite different indeed (or at least, a special case not covered by the much broader question and answer in the linked question)

Comment: @guifa, I mostly agree -- neither alternative given is grammatical. However, I like "There's only us here."

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
There is only us here.
```

Another possible alternative could be:

```
Only we are here.
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case, 'us' is singular, referring to a group such as, for example, 'my family'.  While 'my family' is comprised of many people, the term is singular.

The correct use therefore is: Now, there is only us here.

Comment: So you would allow 'We is going to the shops' if you consider 'we' "singular, referring to a group such as, for example, 'my family' "?