# "What is your name and address" - why "is" instead of "are"?

Tags: grammar

We use "is" with singular but here we use "is" with two things: "name and address". Why?

Comment: Related: [Which is grammatically correct: “There is tea and juice” or “There are tea and juice”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/375299/142322)

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of ["There Is"/"There are" depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not) (There is a closer-looking match, [Plurality of verb depending on plurality of list elements](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not))

Answer (score -3):

If each object of the verb in a sentence is singular, use "is" (eg: There is juice and water.)
If each object of the verb is plural, use "are" (eg: There are juices and water bottles.)(eg: There are bottles of juice and water.)