# "There exist" vs. "There exists"

Tags: grammatical-number

"Prove that there exist 4 people in the waiting room who all know each other..."

This is a part of a math problem. Should the "exist" be "exists" or is it correct the way it currently is?

Comment: Related: [“There exists some people…” or “There exist some people…”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/407695) (Possibly you could find some other similar posts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct as is.  This is easier to see if you rephrase the statement and put the subject ("four people") first:

> "Four people exist in the waiting room who all know each other."

as opposed to

> "Four people exists in the waiting room who all know each other."