# There is a cow and two sheep

Tags: there-is

> There is a cow and two sheep.

The sentence above has caused me some problems. I’ve studied all Murphy’s Grammar books, but couldn’t find a particular rule or exception for this case. My teacher corrected «is» to «are» saying that after a singular noun (a cow) there is a plural “two sheep”. Is there a rule for such a situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are a cow and two sheep in the field?

Comment: It depends on what you're counting. If you're counting the one cow, with the two sheep just tagging along as affiliates of sorts, then "is a cow" is fine. If you're counting all 3 animals, use *are*. Example of the form of the former - *there is a tourist and all her luggage*.

Comment: Your teacher is mistaken. [There is a great answer to this question here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not/140863#140863). Your sentence uses proximity concord.

Comment: @Lawrence So "There is two sheep and a cow" is ok?

Comment: @Araucaria That's different - "is two sheep" is a whole 'nother cattle of fish. :)

Comment: If it's pronounced as contracted "there's" (regardless of how it's spelled), it's fine, IMO.  If it's pronounced as two separate words "there" followed by "is", it's no good.  People's judgements may be clouded by a tendency to spell "there is" as two words while pronouncing it as one contracted form.  As usual, it's the pronunciation that counts.