# How to rewrite "There are a red apple and a green apple on the table."?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following sentence.

**There are a red apple and a green apple on the table.**

Can I rewrite it as follows?

**There are a red and a green apple on the table.**

Or, should I rewrite it as follows?

**There is a red and a green apple on the table.**

Which one is correct? If both are correct, which one is better?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["There Is"/"There are" depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not)

Comment: An English speaker, if forced to say that sentence, would say _There's a red apple and a green apple on the table_. The contraction is almost automatic, like _I'll_ for _I will_ or _he's_ for _he is_. Forms of _be_ are normally contracted, once contracted they don't inflect, and not contracting them draws attention. Of course, this is about English, not writing.