# There is/There are

Tags: grammatical-number, there-is

As a general rule, we use *there is* when its followed by a singular noun and *there are* when the noun that follows is plural.

However, there is that particular line in one of Harry Potter movies that confuses me a lot,

"Broken? There **is** no **bones** left.."

Why is 'is' used here if the noun is plural?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. **Who** says this in the film? Hagrid, for example, has a dialect which might use this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["There Is"/"There are" depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not) 'Existential there couples with either singular or plural verbs (there is / there are, according to the following noun phrase) . . .

Comment: This formal agreement is strictly maintained in academic writing. But in narrative and everyday writing, there is and especially there’s is found even with plural nouns . . . In conversation the combination of there’s with a plural noun is in fact more common than there are, according to the 'Longman Grammar' . . .' [CGEL][Barrie England]